# Measuring execution time using rdtsc within kernel

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I am writing a code to measure the time consumption of a sequence of codes in kernel by loading the codes as module into the kernel. I uses common rdtsc routine to calculate the time. Interesting thing is similar routine running in user mode results in normal values, whereas the results is always 0 when running in kernel mode, no matter how many lines of codes I have added into the time_count function. The calculation I use here is a common matrix product function, and the running cycles should increase rapidly through the increasing of matrix dimension. Can anyone point out the mistakes in my code why I could not measure the cycle number in kernel?

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>

int matrix_product(){
  int array1[500][500], array2[500][500], array3[500][500];
  int i, j, k, sum;

  for(i = 0; i < 50000; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < 50000; j++){
      array1[i][j] = 5*i + j;
      array2[i][j] = 5*i + j;
    }
  }

  for(i = 0; i < 50000; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < 50000; j++){
      for(k = 0; k < 50000; k++)
    sum += array1[i][k]*array2[k][j];
      array3[i][j] = sum;
      sum = 0;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}

static __inline__ unsigned long long rdtsc(void)
{
 unsigned long hi, lo;
 __asm__ __volatile__ ("xorl %%eax,%%eax\ncpuid" ::: "%rax", "%rbx", "%rcx", "%rdx");
 __asm__ __volatile__ ("rdtsc" : "=a"(lo), "=d"(hi));
 return ((unsigned long long)lo) | (((unsigned long long)hi)<<32) ;
}

static int my_init(void)
{
  unsigned long str, end, curr, best, tsc, best_curr;
  long i, t;

#define time_count(codes) for(i=0; i<120000; i++){str=rdtsc(); codes; end=rdtsc(); curr=end-str; if(curr<best)best=curr;}

 best = ~0;
 time_count();
 tsc = best;

 best = ~0;
 time_count(matrix_product());
 best_curr = best;
 printk("<0>matrix product: %lu ticks\n", best_curr-tsc);

 return 0;
}

static void my_exit(void){
  return;
}

module_init(my_init);
module_exit(my_exit);`
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: I want to know how to change this code in order to make it measure execution cycle number in kernel correctly.

Comment: I see. BTW: rdtsc is a _terrible_ instruction: it needs to drain the instruction pipeline (IIRC you need to fetch CPUID too, to get reliable results), maybe even the TLB, and it sometimes even forces the cores to resynchronise their clocks. It could well be that the kernel somehow disables this instruction, I don't know how, but for userspace execution the instruction can somehow be disabled, maybe also for ring-0.

Comment: Oh, I see. It is true that rdtsc will impact the overall performance by controlling the pipeline. Actually, in my project, I try to measure some execution time of context switches or some relatively small amount of codes, so I think rdtsc is pretty light-weighted and might work well in this scenario. Would you mind recommend some other functions which could work better in my case? Thanx

Comment: @wildplasser That is not how `rdtsc` works; it is quite fast but (on out-of-order CPUs) not very accurate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rdtsc` is not guaranteed to be available on every CPU, or to run at a constant rate, or be consistent between different cores.

You should use a reliable and portable function like `getrawmonotonic` unless you have special requirements for the timestamps.

If you really want to use cycles directly, the kernel already defines [get_cycles](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=get_cycles) and [cpuid](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=cpuid) functions for this.

Comment: Thanks, I believe rdtsc is optimized and does not work in kernel for my testing.

Comment: @CL: Even 2013 rdtsc was invariant for a long time.